# Can I specify capacitor config file on build?

Tags: config, capacitor

I want to create two versions of an app with slightly different content. Therefore I thought about having two "www" directories (lets say "www-foo" and "www-bar") and tell capacitor in the capacitor.config.json which one to use (with "webDir" setting). Also the "appId" should be different then.

So I guessed the easiest way would be to have these capacitor.config.json files with different "appId" and "webDir" settings and when running the build script to specify which config file to use (like it's known from webpack with --config flag). But I can't find any information if it's possible to specify the config file to use for building the app.

**Is it just not possible (yet) or am I too stupid to find it? :)**

Otherwise I would try to create the capacitor.config.json file with webpack before running the capacitor build script.

*I used [this article](https://medium.com/@SmileFX/a-complete-guide-building-a-capacitorjs-application-using-pure-javascript-and-webpack-37d00f11720d) as a guide for my project.*

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if exist any option for two or more AppID/webDir in Capacitor.

But understanding you necessity my suggest is create a custom build script in Node.js that change info in capacitor.config.ts (appId) > build (www/www-Two) > sync & copy to platform

Comment: Yeah... I was thinking about that (that was what I meant by "creating capacitor.config.json with webpack"). I'll try some more things if I could find another way. If not, I think I'll use diffent build scripts. I'll let you know if I find other ways ;)